# How to fix "assignment makes integer without a cast" **Update**

Tags: c, command-line

Okay here's the program I have typed up(stdio.h is included also):

```
/* function main begins program execution */
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x; /*first number input*/
    int y; /*second number input*/
    int sum; /* variable in which sum will be stored */
    int product; /* variable in which product will be stored */
    int quotient; /* variable in which x divided by y will be stored */
    int md; /* variable in which the modulo division of x divided by y */

    x = argv[2]; /*assign total to x*/
    y = argv[3]; /*assign total to y*/

    if (argc ==3) {
       sum = x + y; /* assign total to sum */
       printf("%d\n",sum); /*print sum*/

       product = x * y; /*assign total to product*/
       printf("%d\n", product); /*print product*/

       quotient = x / y; /*assign total to quotient*/
       printf("%d\n", quotient); /*print quotient*/

       md = x % y; /*assign total to md*/
       printf("%d\n", md); /*print md*/
    } /*end if*/

    if (argc !=3) {
       printf("need two integers\n"); /*need two integers*/
    }

    return 0; /*indicate program ran successfully*/
} /*end of main*/
```

When I run it through the compiler it says that in lines 15 and 16 (x= and y= lines) "assignment makes  integer from pointer without a cast." How do I fix this?

**I changed it to x=atoi(argv[2]) and y=atoi(argv[3]) and it fixed that problem. But as always something else has now screwed up. Now when I run the program I get:

163 [main] a_4312 _cygtls::handle_exceptions: Error while dumping state

Segmentation fault

I read that this means I didn't allocate memory for the output or something like that...can anyone give me a hand here?**

Comment: Side Note: You have over-commenting your code. It's obvious that your printf statements are printing something. Therefore, you don't need to add the comment "print product", or whatever.

Comment: Also, better variable names can be self-documenting. Instead of x and y, consider using first and second.

Comment: Ya, there is a lot of commenting, but our teacher wants us to do it that way.

Comment: WRT to the seg fault, this is probably due to your reading of the argv array, you should move the assignment inside the if (so the if is protecting it) and it should be x = argv[1] and y = argv[2] - c has zero base arrays (they index from zero to length-1).

Comment: some picking: your second if should be an else, because if the first if succeedes, the second expression does not need to be evaluated. btw, you omitted a comment a closing brace before return.

about commenting: you surly should not comment what it does, but why it does something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error was due to you assigning text to a number. You actually need to call a function to convert between the 2 atoi.

The most important runtime error is the seg fault, this is caused by using the wrong indexes into the array, c has 0 based arrays so the first element is 0, this means the 2 arguments you want are 1 and 2 (since the first argument is the executable's name).

Finally, you may want to check the y value before the divide and mod since if it's 0 you'll get divide by zero problems.

```
x = atoi(argv[1]); /*assign total to x*/
y = atoi(argv[2]); /*assign total to y*/
```

Comment: This will obviously crash.. it should be 1 & 2.

Comment: I actually pointed that out in the comments of the question - have updated here.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers you get passed are argv[1] and argv[2], not argv[2] and argv[3].

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the provided solution, you should also check whether the required arguments are there (move the last if block to before the assignment to to x and y) before trying to pass them to `atoi` or you will get run-time issues.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[2]` gives you a `char *`. You need conversion to an `int`:

```
x = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your command line is:

prompt>>  myprogram 5 6

argv[0] should be the program name (myprogram)
argv[1] should be the first parameter ("5")
argv[2] should be the second parameter ("6")

I think you're referring to argv[3], which doesn't exist.